# Apt Update Error - Focal Fossa No Longer Supported

Tags: apt, updates

I am getting the following error when running 'apt update' on my Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS machine.:

```
The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
```

I looked up what it means by 'focal' and that translates into Ubuntu 20.04 (which is the most current LTS release at the time of posting).

How can the most recent LTS release, which I believe should be supported for five years, no longer be supported?

This is the full output from `sudo apt update` and `lsb_release -a`:

```
$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for administrator: 

Hit:1 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                           
Get:2 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]                                                                          
Get:3 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]                                                                                                  
Get:4 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [1,170 kB]                                                                                                        
Ign:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                                                                                                          
Get:6 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [282 kB]                                                                               
Get:7 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [851 kB]                                      
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                 
Hit:9 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                            
Err:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security Release                                                                
  404  Not Found [IP: 31.170.160.150 80]
Get:11 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [351 kB]                               
Get:12 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [944 B]                 
Get:13 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [10.3 kB]
Err:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu focal Release                                                        
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

$ lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Checking the IP:

```
$ dig @8.8.8.8 -t any security.ubuntu.com

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> @8.8.8.8 -t any security.ubuntu.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 64332
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 4, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;security.ubuntu.com.       IN  ANY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
security.ubuntu.com.    59  IN  AAAA    2001:67c:1562::18
security.ubuntu.com.    59  IN  AAAA    2001:67c:1562::15
security.ubuntu.com.    59  IN  A   91.189.91.38
security.ubuntu.com.    59  IN  A   91.189.91.39

;; Query time: 288 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Mon Aug 23 22:25:57 NZST 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 136
```

```
$ dig -t any security.ubuntu.com

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> -t any security.ubuntu.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 10286
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;security.ubuntu.com.       IN  ANY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
security.ubuntu.com.    19  IN  A   91.189.91.39
security.ubuntu.com.    19  IN  A   91.189.91.38

;; Query time: 16 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Mon Aug 23 22:30:44 NZST 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 80
```

Comment: Try again. I just looked and the file is indeed present on that server.

Comment: Are you actually running 20.04 or do you have sources from more than one version/distro?

Comment: Hi user535733 - I just retried and pasted the output into the question (I can't work out how to get the code tags to work - sorry!)  Alan.

Comment: Hi Nmath - I ran an 'lsb_release -a' and included the results in the original question above.  Thanks, Alan.

Comment: `security.ubuntu.com` is a `91.189.x.x` IP for me. I'm not sure what `31.170.160.150` is, but it doesn't look like a Canonical site to me. It's not in [this list of Canonical-owned IP addresses](https://ipinfo.io/AS41231) either. Check your DNS settings.

Comment: Hi muru - Interesting.  I included the results of a 'dig' in my OP and I also get a 91.189 IP.  I get the same if I 'dig' @ my local DNS resolver (172.25.25.254) which is the immediate DNs lookup destination and gateway for the machine, and also if  just 'dig' the hostname without specifiying the DNS server (dig -t any security.ubuntu.com) .  Not sure where to go from here, but this appears to be the issue?  Alan.